# VueJS Adding data from query parameters

Tags: javascript, pushstate, vue-router, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a small purely client-side VueJS application that uses `VueRouter` to update the URL when data is entered into the application, so users can use the URL to refresh the page and reload their data into the app when refreshing the page.  The data is stored in query parameters, ex.:

```
.../app.html#/?time=300&time=300&distance=300&distance=300&unit=m&unit=m
```

The data is parsed as needed by the `router`, but when I add the data to my empty `performance` array, the `:class` attribute in my markup raises a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Where `undefined` is the `performances` array.  I have narrowed this issue down to the `:class` attribute inside of the `v-for` performance loop by removing the `:class` from the app's markup and successfully rendered the site.  I am guessing that the `performances` data array has not been passed to the `:class`.

I did not see any mention of this type of routing in the [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) documentation.  How should data be passed from the URL query parameters into the application?   Here is my relevant code (condensed for the sake of brevity):

```
// js file
var router = new VueRouter({}); // empty because no routes, just query parameters, so no need for list

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            performances: [],
            units: units,
            newPerformance: {
                distance: {
                    value: '',
                    units: units.distance.options[0]
                },
                time: {
                    formatted: '',
                    value: ''
                },
            },
            editingPerformance: null,
        }
    },
    router: router,
    watch: {
        performances: {
            handler: function() {
                this.drawChart();
                this.updateURL();
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
    updateURL: function() {
        var times = this.performances.map(function(v) {
                return v.time.value
            }),
            distances = this.performances.map(function(v) {
                return v.distance.value
            }),
            units = this.performances.map(function(v) {
                return v.distance.units.value
            });
        router.push({
            query: {
                time: times,
                distance: distances,
                dunit: units
            }
        });
    }
    ....
});
```

HTML file

```
...
<div v-for="(performance, index) in performances" :class="{'card-list': performances.length > 1 }">
...
</div>
...
```

I have read the  [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) documentation and tried such solutions as:

```
    Vue.nextTick(function() {
        this.performances.push(performance);
    })
```

and

```
    Vue.set(app, 'performances',performanceArray);
```

which result in the same error.  I can provide more code upon request.

Edit: Adding stack traces:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance: warn @ vue.js:513
Vue._render @ vue.js:2934
(anonymous function) @ vue.js:2335
get @ vue.js:1643run @ vue.js:1712
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.js:1530
(anonymous function) @ vue.js:465
nextTickHandler @ vue.js:414
```

followed immediately by:

```
vue.js:427 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
logError @ vue.js:427
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a component and including that via your app instead of trying to make those methods in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might be setting it to something other than an array somewhere in your code. You instantiated it as an array, and .length only works on arrays and strings so if you set it to an object, json, or anything else it will error out. Vue.nextTick has a callback that won't carry "this" over into it unless you set it to a variable in the same scope as your Vue.nextTick function. something like

```
var self = this;

//inside nextTick

self.performances.push(performance);
```

but i would imagine that you shouldn't have to use nextTick because nextTick updates after the DOM has been re-rendered. the push() function will trigger a dom re-render, which will make your page responsive. If you wait for nextTick then it may never update until you change something else.

```
<div v-if="performances.length" v-for="(performance, index) in performances" 
:class="performances.length > 1 ? 'card-list' : ''">
...
</div>
```

The v-if attribute will make sure that it doesn't render until the content is there.

That should fix your problem

You can also do {{ performance }} to find out what is exactly in the object, and Google chrome has a vue-debugger extension. It shows you a live model of all of your data properties. I would recommend using it.

Comment: It turned out that I was having a different issue. On a different line (that I overlooked, of course), I had the line `:class="{'hide': performance.label.length === 0, ... }`, where label isn't defined in my router. Once I took that out, my code worked as expected.  I'll mark your answer as correct, since it would have been the correct answer to my issue had I set the `performances` array to something other than an array. I just verified this to be sure this would have fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Absolutely, Thank you!